# Why is redux.props.reducer returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a function from actions folder that fetches a url using axios and that has worked. But it's getting the data from reducer that isn't working for some reason.
I have mapStateToProps function defined

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        popular: state.popular.results
    };
}
```

and I connect it using redux connect function

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Search);
```

But when i try to print the data, it gives me undefined

```
switch (this.props.popular){
            case null:
                console.log(this.props.popular);
                return;
            case false:
                console.log(this.props.popular);
                return;
            default:
                console.log(this);
                return;
        }
```

The default in the switch case returns an object that contains the data
[image]

As you can see in props.popular, there is an array of objects,
but when i try to print this.props.popular in the default case in the switch statement, it get undefined. Why does it show that the array exists when i just print `this` , but when I try to print `this.props.popular` , it doesn't seem to be able to understand it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In default case add  `return default:
                return this.props.popular`

Comment: are you using the connected Search component or the class Search, can you show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `default` case should contain something, because redux uses a few of its own actions to initialize, so, when your dispatch happens, this reducer returned `undefined` already.